# Decorator can't find positional argument even though it has both of the needed arguments

Tags: python, decorator, wrapper, python-decorators

I am trying to write a decorator that allows you to set the named arguments of an arbitrary function to default values, that has dictionary with appropriate values provided. Here's the code:

```
from functools import wraps
from inspect import signature

def default_args(defaults):
    def decorator(func):
        sig = signature(func)
        for param in sig.parameters.values():
            if (param.kind == param.POSITIONAL_ONLY and param.name in defaults):
                raise ValueError(f"Parameter {param.name} of function {func.name} is positional only and cannot be set by default")
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            bound = sig.bind(*args, **kwargs)
            for name, val in defaults.items():
                if name not in bound.arguments:
                    bound.arguments[name] = val
            return func(*bound.args, **bound.kwargs)
        wrapper.__signature__ = sig.replace(
            parameters=[p.replace(default=defaults.get(p.name, p.default)) for p in sig.parameters.values()]
        )
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@default_args({'b': 15, 'd': 17, 'c': 8})

def foo (a, /, b, *args, c=5, d, **kwargs):
    """My Function"""
    print(f"{a=} {b=} {args=} {c=} {d=} {kwargs=}")
    

def foo_wrapped(a, /, b, *args, c=5, d, **kwargs):
    """My wrapped function"""
    print(f"{a=} {b=} {args=} {c=} {d=} {kwargs=}")
    
foo_wrapped(10, d=22)

foo(10, 20, d=11)
```

It works great when both positional arguments are present, feeding all of the other ones in:

```
foo(10, 20, d=11)
a=10 b=20 args=() c=8 d=11 kwargs={}
```

But when one is missing, a TypeError appears:

```
foo_wrapped(10, d=22)
TypeError: foo_wrapped() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'
```

I understand that it somehow doesn't receive the b argument from the decorator, and I feel that I'm missing something simple, so I'm stumped. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `foo_wrapped` is not decorated at all in your code. Only `foo` is, with `@default_args`. And `foo_wrapped` does indeed have two non-optional parameters `a` and `b`. In your example call, you failed to pass `b`. So I am not sure what confuses you here.

Comment: If I remove `foo` function and just leave `foo_wrapped`, the error is the same, even though I'm passing it through the decorator - shouldn't it work if I give non-optional parameters to `@default_args` and then only give one non-optional one?

Comment: No, the error is not the same. The error then occurs in the `Signature.bind` call because you are trying to bind an incomplete set of arguments to the _original_ function signature, i.e. not that of the wrapper, but that of the non-wrapped function. You may want to try out [`bind_partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Signature.bind_partial) instead. That should work.

Comment: `bind_partial` seems to be working - thank you very much!